# How to get Latitude and longitude from given address in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

- This is my jQuery code:

  ```
        $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#landmark").focusout(function(){
             var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
             var address = $("#landmark").val();
             if(address!="")
             {
             geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, 
             status) {

               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                 var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                 $("#lat").val(latitude);
                 $("#longi").val(longitude); 
                 }   
             });
             }
           });
         });
  ```

  This doesn't work with Codeigniter - do I need to add some library files in Codeigniter?

Comment: this is pure jquery

Comment: Press F12 when using Chrome and then see if there are any error messages.

Comment: You could also provide some more information about why it's not working